# How many times does the exec() can be called in fork()

Tags: posix

There problem is that i am calling fork() and in that i am calling exec twice,once in the parent and once in the child..i just came up with this new idea of calling exec multiple times by creating more childs..but what happens is that only the first parent and child call exec, the rest is just ignored
Now i understand that once an exec is called you dont come back, but i have this curiosity of running multiple execs, is there any way i could do this?
btw i did try to create a child and a parent outside the first parent but the output was still the same

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    pid_t parent=fork();
    if (parent>0)
    {
        printf("This is the parent \n");
        execl("/home/desertstorm/OS/Final/Exec_Calls/exec1.out","./exec1.out",argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],NULL);
        wait(NULL);
        if (parent<0)
        printf("Fork failed\n");
        pid_t child=fork();
        if (child>0)
        {
            printf("This is the second parent\n");
            execl("/home/desertstorm/OS/Final/Exec_Calls/exec3.out","./exec3.out",argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],NULL);
            wait(NULL);
            pid_t child1=fork();
            if (child1>0)
            {
                printf("This is the third parent\n");
                execl("/home/desertstorm/OS/Final/Exec_Calls/exec1.out","./exec1.out",argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],NULL);
                wait(NULL);
            }
            if (child1==0)
                {
                    printf("This is the third child\n"); 
                    execl("/home/desertstorm/OS/Final/Exec_Calls/exec4.out","./exec4.out",argv[4],argv[5],argv[6],NULL);
                }
    if (parent==0)
    {
        printf("This is the child\n");
        execl("/home/desertstorm/OS/Final/Exec_Calls/exec2.out","./exec2.out",argv[4],argv[5],argv[6],NULL);
    }
        }
        if (child==0)
        {
            printf("This is the second child\n");
            execl("/home/desertstorm/OS/Final/Exec_Calls/exec4.out","./exec4.out",argv[4],argv[5],argv[6],NULL);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If nothing goes wrong, none of the `exec` functions return. So you can call it only once. Once you successfully call an `exec` function, your code is replaced and any code you have after the `exec` call will not run.

Comment: " i understand that once an exec is called you dont come back". So you understand that you cannot follow the call to `exec` with code you want to be executed, right?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to create a new process (without going into the intricacies of threads being processes as well) in UNIX based systems is to call fork(). Once one of the exec functions is called, the child is replaced by the program being exec'ed, so any subsequent instruction in the forked child will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the `exec` never returns (unless it fails), so the code to create the second child never executes.

You could have the parent call `fork` some number of times, and have each child call `exec`, and then have the parent call `exec`.

Alternatively, the parent can call `fork` followed by `exec`, and the child can do the same, so it creates another child, and so on.  When you've created enough processes, the last child calls `exec` without calling `fork` to stop the chain.